# How do I make a code run when clicked on and take input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script and I want it to run when I click on it, but when I saved it as exe as other people suggested and click on it, it only flashes cmd for a split second and it does not show anything nor does it take the input it needs.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the script's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a "pause" at the end of your script.
This will ensure the cmd doesn't close after your script runs and if your script hasn't run successfully then this will at least let you see the error message

Answer (score 0):

Use **Auto Py To Exe** for converting python scripts into executable files.
[Here's a description.](https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi)

If you want your script to stay on screen and not open-close immediately (flash), you can make it wait for a useless input like this:

```
print('start of the script')
#do sth here
print('end of the script')
draft = input()
```